# Process dies if profiling is turned on

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I want to profile Tensorflow model on CloudML. When I use tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE), my process dies with non zero exit code without details of what happened.

I tried adding and removing the code which turns on this option, and there's 100% correlation between this option and the death of the process.

The error message is 'The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 250. Termination reason: Error. To find out more about why your job exited please check the logs'

How can I diagnose and fix this problem?

Comment: I'm an engineer on Cloud ML Engine. Sorry for the trouble would you mind sharing a job id where this happens? If you don't want to post it publicly you can email it to us at cloudml-feedback@google.com.

Comment: @JeremyLewi Thanks for the quick reply. It's a toy example, I am just learning tensorflow and experimenting with cifar dataset on gpu. The job id is cifar_20170430_215857 If you need other information, let me know.

Comment: @JeremyLewi Are there any updates on it? Did the job_id help you to reproduce the problem? If needed, I can send you the whole code if needed to reproduce it.

Comment: We are investigating. We think it might be the same segfault as in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651296/google-cloud-ml-exited-with-a-non-zero-status-of-245-when-training) so you might want to try the workaround in that question (i.e. using TF 1.1.0).

Comment: @JeremyLewi After upgrading to TF 1.1.0 exception disappeared, but I don't see any profiling information from gpu in tensorboard. It all grayed out.

Comment: @JeremyLewi The job id is  cifar_20170502_215031

Comment: I reproduced the same problem on local machine. It was fixed by adding /usr/local/cuda-8.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64 to LD_PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed by using tensorflow 1.1.0 instead of 1.0.0. Though, profiling information wasn't shown.

Answer (score 0):

For your question, basically the exit status means your code got a SIGABRT during run.

Update:
There is a issue of loading libcupti. Cloud ML Engine has found a bug related to it. Fix is in progress. The problem will be resolved in future release.